# Code coverage using dotCover - FAKE F#MAKE

Tags: f#, f#-interactive, f#-3.0, f#-fake

I am trying to use dotCover in FAKE .I am getting an error i.e. `DotCoverNUnit is not defined` .I think this is the problem with the package .

Here is my Code for DotCover in FAKE :

```
let filters = ""
Target "TestCoverage" (fun _ ->
    !! ("D:/Test/Project/Project1/UnitTests/UnitTest.dll")
        |> DotCoverNUnit (fun p -> 
            { p with
                Output = testDir @@ "NUnitDotCover.snapshot"
                Filters = filters }) nunitOptions
)
```

Please tell me how to install DotCover in Fake or how to use this . This would be very helpful .

Answer (score 1):

The `Fake.DotCover` module is not auto-opened, so its functions aren't available until you do `open Fake.DotCover` near the top of your script.

Unfortunately, the FAKE API documentation currently isn't very good at telling you which modules are auto-opened and which ones need `open (modulename)` in order to expose their functions.

**Update:** The way you should be calling `DotCoverNUnit` is as follows:

```
let filters = ""
Target "TestCoverage" (fun _ ->
    !! ("D:/Test/Project/Project1/UnitTests/UnitTest.dll")
        |> DotCoverNUnit
            (fun p -> { p with Output = testDir @@ "NUnitDotCover.snapshot"
                               Filters = filters })
            (fun nunitOptions -> nunitOptions)
)
```

Or, if you want to *change* some of the NUnit options:

```
let filters = ""
Target "TestCoverage" (fun _ ->
    !! ("D:/Test/Project/Project1/UnitTests/UnitTest.dll")
        |> DotCoverNUnit
            (fun dotCoverOptions ->
                 { dotCoverOptions with Output = testDir @@ "NUnitDotCover.snapshot"
                                        Filters = filters })
            (fun nunitOptions ->
                 { nunitOptions with ExcludeCategory = "Manual,LongRunning"
                                     DisableShadowCopy = true })
)
```

See http://fsharp.github.io/FAKE/apidocs/fake-nunitcommon-nunitparams.html for the complete list of what NUnit options are available from inside FAKE.

Comment: I tried this , now it is giving another error 
i.e. `The Value or Constructor nunitOptions is not defined `.

Comment: The `DotCoverNUnit` wants *two* functions as parameters. The first function takes a `dotCoverOptions` record (which will be initialized to the default DotCover options) and returns that record with your own modifications (if any). That one, you have. The second function should take an `nunitOptions` record and should return that record with your own modifications. If you want the default NUnit options, then just write it as `(fun nunitOptions -> nunitOptions)`. I'll update my answer with sample code.

Comment: @ rmunn : , Thanks for your efforts and good suggestions that you always give ,  I tried this also , it is still showing some error , I have opened another question , that might clear the issue in detail . please have a look at this .
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42998375/code-coverage-using-dotcover-throws-an-error-fake-fmake