# Code coverage using dotCover throws an error - FAKE F#MAKE

Tags: f#, f#-interactive, f#-3.0, f#-data, f#-fake

I am trying  to use DotCover in FAKE , but it is throwing some error , as I am new to FAKE as well as F# , it's becoming difficult for me to understand the root cause of the problem . Here is the code :

```
 #r "D:/FAKEProject/Fake/packages/FAKE/tools/FakeLib.dll"
    open Fake
    open Fake.DotCover
    let testDir = "D:/FAKEProject/Fake/test/"
    let filters = ""
    Target "Clean" (fun _ ->
        CleanDirs [testDir]
    )
    Target "TestCoverage" (fun _ ->
        !! ("D:/FAKEProject/Fake/UnitTest/UnitTest.dll")
            |> DotCoverNUnit
                (fun p -> { p with Output = testDir @@ "NUnitDotCover.snapshot"
                                   ToolPath = "D:/tools/dotCover/dotCover.exe"
                                   Filters = filters })                              
                (fun nunitOptions -> nunitOptions)
    )
    "Clean"
        ==> "TestCoverage"
    RunTargetOrDefault "TestCoverage"`
```

It is giving this error

```
System.Exception: Error running D:/tools/dotCover/dotCover.exe with exitcode -1
   at Fake.DotCover.buildParamsAndExecute@124-6.Invoke(String message) in C:\code\fake\src\app\FakeLib\DotCover.fs:line 124
   at Fake.DotCover.buildParamsAndExecute[a](a parameters, FSharpFunc`2 buildArguments, String toolPath, String workingDir, Boolean failBuild) in C:\code\fake\src\app\FakeLib\DotCover.fs:line 124
   at Fake.DotCover.DotCoverNUnit(FSharpFunc`2 setDotCoverParams, FSharpFunc`2 setNUnitParams, IEnumerable`1 assemblies) in C:\code\fake\src\app\FakeLib\DotCover.fs:line 190
   at FSI_0005.DotCover.clo@16-2.Invoke(Unit _arg2) in D:\FAKEProject\Fake\DotCover.fsx:line 17
   at Fake.TargetHelper.runSingleTarget(TargetTemplate`1 target) in C:\code\fake\src\app\FakeLib\TargetHelper.fs:line 492`
```

I am not able to understand why it is searching in C:\code\fake\src\app\fakelib\dotcover.fs
and what is dotcover.fs it is looking for 
How to solve this problem , as I am stuck at this error , If anyone can help me regarding this , it would be very helpful .

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

The mysterious `C:\code\fake\src\app\FakeLib\DotCover.fs` line is simply telling you the filename (and line number) of the source file that threw the error. Not the filename on *your* system, but the filename on the system where your `FAKE.exe` file was built. In other words, it's just telling you where the exception was thrown from.

Looking at the FAKE source code, I see that line 124 is near the end of the following block of code:

```
let buildParamsAndExecute parameters buildArguments toolPath workingDir failBuild =
    let args = buildArguments parameters
    trace (toolPath + " " + args)
    let result = ExecProcess (fun info ->  
              info.FileName <- toolPath
              info.WorkingDirectory <- getWorkingDir workingDir
              info.Arguments <- args) TimeSpan.MaxValue
    let ExitCodeForFailedTests = -3
    if (result = ExitCodeForFailedTests && not failBuild) then 
        trace (sprintf "DotCover %s exited with errorcode %d" toolPath result)
    else if (result = ExitCodeForFailedTests && failBuild) then 
        failwithf "Failing tests, use ErrorLevel.DontFailBuild to ignore failing tests. Exited %s with errorcode %d" toolPath result
    else if (result <> 0) then 
        failwithf "Error running %s with exitcode %d" toolPath result
    else 
        trace (sprintf "DotCover exited successfully")
```

The `failwithf` function is F#'s equivalent of "throw new Exception()", but it lets you specify a message (using `printfn`-style format codes like `%s`) to go with the exception. So there's nothing mysterious going on here in F#, it's just that your `D:/tools/dotCover/dotCover.exe` program has returned a -1 return code. Return codes of -1 usually mean "generic error", so that's not much help in figuring out the cause.

Your next troubleshooting step is to run your `dotCover.exe` program manually, giving it the same arguments that FAKE is giving it (shouldn't be too hard to figure out, since the FAKE option records are usually pretty well-named) and the same input. Then see what error messages, if any, `dotCover.exe` is printing out before it fails.

Comment: I tried running test cases from console using dotcover and nunit.console.exe , then 1 unit test case is ignored and rest working fine and report is also generated .and it shows analysed application exited with Code 1

Comment: I added `TargetExecutable = "D:/Project/tools/NUnit.Runners.2.6.3/nunit-console.exe"` and it is working now .